# How can I run XCUITest on real devices with different versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xctest

I want to test my app on Firebase Labs, which has different devices running different versions of iOS. In order to do this I need to 'Build for Testing', targeting 'Any iOS Device (arm 64)'. This ends up creating an AppNameUITest-Runner.app to drive the UITest on the device. The problem is the driver app is built with the latest deployment target, while the test devices at Firebase Labs are all on older versions of iOS. So when I upload my package, the iOS 14.7 devices can't run the 15.2 driver app, and the tests fail. Is the any way I can fix or work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to do that if you are using the latest deployment target and they don't support devices with that iOS version. The fix would be to build the app with lower deployment target.